# Start i2 analyst notebook from browser

Tags: windows, registry, pluggableprotocol

I want to start i2 analyst notebook (IBM product) via anchor in browser. I was told it should be possible to do so using Custom URI scheme, that should be registered in windows registry along with the i2 app.
I managed to find Registry **LinkNotebook.Application.7** or **LinkNotebook.Chart.7**. LinkNotebook.Chart.7 has shell -> open -> command folders specified, linking to the correct .exe.

```
<a href="LinkNotebook.Application.7:">open ANB</a>
```

This link actually prompts dialog in chrome
[image]

But when **Open** is clicked, nothing happens.
In **IE**, another modal opens afterwards

[image]